# Ionic2 - Reusing Service with TabsPage breaks app, causes runtime error on startup

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ionic2, circular-dependency

I am new to Ionic2 and have come across an error from what seems to be a circular dependency with a page that I can't figure out.

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HiredJobsPage: (?).
```

I whittled my code down to bare bones in order to pinpoint the problem; it has something to do with TabsPage.

I'm using Ionic2's tabs template project, in which is a tabs.ts file. This file specifies 3 tabs to be shown at the bottom of the page, each linked to another page.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { JobRequestsPage} from '../job-requests/job-requests';
import { HiredJobsPage } from '../hired-jobs/hired-jobs';
import { ProfilePage } from "../profile/profile";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = ProfilePage;
  tab2Root: any = JobRequestsPage;
  tab3Root: any = HiredJobsPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

I also have a very basic service, that does nothing other than assign an instance of TabsPage into a local variable.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {TabsPage} from "../../pages/tabs/tabs";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  foo: any = TabsPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

This service works fine, and the project compiles and runs, when MyService is injected into only one component. However, when I inject the service into two components, the project breaks and won't run.  If I assign another page (ProfilePage, JobRequests, null, etc.) into the foo variable, things are fine; it is only TabsPage which causes the error. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [angular dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html) and [forward reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#forwardref) in particular.Another blog post is [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html)

> This service works fine, and the project compiles and runs, when
>   MyService is injected into only one component. However, when I inject
>   the service into two components, the project breaks and won't run. If
>   I assign another page (ProfilePage, JobRequests, null, etc.) into the
>   foo variable, things are fine; it is only TabsPage which causes the
>   error.

Your tabs page(T) refers to classes: P,J and H.
Service(S) refers to T.

```
     T        S
    /|\       |
   / | \      |
  P  J  H     T
```

Based on which classes you choose to inject your service,you will end up with circular dependency of pointing back to Tabs Page (T).
A solution is to use forward reference when you inject the service.

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => MyService )) myService)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your detailed answer.